# ! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg

Tags: tables, arrays

I'm having the following error message

> ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
>   *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
>   *geometry* detected driver: pdftex No file main.bbl.
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.29  \begin{tabular}{|l|c{4cm}|}

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

\input{structure.tex}

\hypersetup{pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|l|c{4cm}|}
    \hline
    Classe de caractère & Siginification\\
    \hline

    [abc$^\wedge$] & Un unique caractère qui peut être a, b ou c \\

    \hline

    $[^abc]$ & Le $^\wedge$ exprime la négation : cette classe représente un unique caractère, \tabularnewline qui peut prendre toutes les valeurs, sauf a, b et c\\

 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Based on what muzimuzhi and David Carlisle wrote, new code is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

\input{structure.tex}

\hypersetup{pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|l|wc{4cm}|}
    \hline
    Classe de caractère & Siginification\\
    \hline

    [abc$^\wedge$] & Un unique caractère qui peut être a, b ou c \\

    \hline

    $[^abc]$ & Le $^\wedge$ exprime la négation : cette classe représente un unique caractère, \tabularnewline qui peut prendre toutes les valeurs, sauf a, b et c\\

 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

New error message is:

> ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
>   *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
>   *geometry* detected driver: pdftex No file main.bbl.
>
> ! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (w): `c' used.
>
> See the array package documentation for explanation. Type  H  
>   for immediate help.  ...
>                                                      l.18   \begin{tabular}{|l|wc{4cm}|}

After Js bibra answer, I'm having the following code and the rendering as showed on the picture below:

```
    [![\begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}}
        \toprule
            Classe de caractère & Signification\\
        \midrule

            \[abc$^\wedge$\] & Un unique caractère qui peut être a, b ou c \\
        \midrule
            $\[^abc\]$ & Le $^\wedge$ exprime la négation: cette classe représente un unique caractère, \tabularnewline qui peut prendre toutes les valeurs, sauf a, b et c\\
        \midrule
            $\[a-zA-Z\]$ & Le - signifie que tous les caractères entre ses bornes sont valides.  Cette classe représente un unique caractère alphabétique, minuscule ou majuscule.\\
        \midrule
            $\[a-gmn\]$ & Autre exemple d'union: cette classe \tabularnewline est constituée de tous les caractères compris entre a et g, du caractère m et du caractère n.\\
        \midrule
            $\[a-g\[A-G\]\]$ & On peut inclure des classes les unes dans les autres. Cette classe représente un unique caractère, compris entre a et g, en minuscule ou en majuscule. Elle est équivalente à \[a-gA-G\].\\
        \midrule
            $ \[a-g\&\&\[c-k\]\] $ & Le signe $\&\&$ représente l'intersection. On fait donc là l'intersection entre la classe \[a-g\] et la classe \[c-k\]. Il s'agit donc de la classe \[c-g\].\\
        \midrule
            $\[a-g\&\&\[^\wedge cd\]\]$ & Ici on réalise l'intersection entre la classe qui représente tous les caractères de a à g, et celle qui représente tous les caractères, sauf c et d. Il reste donc a, b, e, f et g, que l'on peut aussi écrire \[abefg\] ou \[abe-g\].\\
        \midrule
            $\[a-z\&\&\[^m-p\]\]$ & Autre exemple: \tabularnewline ici on réalise l'intersection de tous les caractères compris entre a et z, et de tous les caractères sauf ceux compris entre m et p. Il nous reste donc \[a-lq-z\].\\
        \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}][1]][1]
```

Comment: There is no `c{3cm}` syntax. Load `array` package and use `m{3cm}` instead.

Comment: if your array package is not too old, `wc{3cm}`

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ cProg wants the column centred but `m{3cm}` will make justified paragraphs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Thanks to point out.

Comment: @cProg would u like to accept and/or upvote the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax `c{<width>}` for a centered column of fixed width.

If your version the `array` package is 2.4f (2017/11/07) or newer you can use the column type `w{<alignment>}{<width>}` that is

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|w{c}{4cm}|}
```

for a centered column of fixed width (this needs the `array` package, of course). However, this overprints if the cell contents is wider than the width specified. And this would be the case for the table in your MWE.

I suggest to instead define a suitable paragraph column yourself:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

This need the `array` package, too, of course.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|C{4cm}|}
  \hline
    Classe de caractère & Siginification\\
  \hline
    [abc$^\wedge$] & Un unique caractère qui peut être a, b ou c \\
  \hline
    $[^abc]$ & Le $^\wedge$ exprime la négation: cette classe représente un
             unique caractère, qui peut prendre toutes les valeurs, sauf a,
             b et c \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If I understand you table correctly I also like to suggest not using mathmode but verbatim:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newcommand\code[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|C{4cm}|}
  \hline
    Classe de caractère & Siginification\\
  \hline
    \verb+[abc^]+ & Un unique caractère qui peut être \code{a}, \code{b} et
                    \code{c} \\
  \hline
    \verb+[^abc]+ & Le \verb+^+ exprime la négation: cette classe représente un
                    unique caractère, qui peut prendre toutes les valeurs, sauf
                    \code{a}, \code{b} et \code{c} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    \begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}}
    \toprule
    Classe de caractère & Siginification\\
    \midrule

    [abc$^\wedge$] & Un unique caractère qui peut être a, b ou c \\

    \midrule

    $[^abc]$ & Le $^\wedge$ exprime la négation : cette classe représente un unique caractère, \tabularnewline qui peut prendre toutes les valeurs, sauf a, b et c\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]